# Can't call up SpFeature by Display Name - sharepoint 2010 power shell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am running the sharepoint 2010 Management Shell and I am did this

```
Get-SPFeature –DocumentRoutingResources –Site http://sp2010 |ft -auto
```

> Get-SPFeature : A parameter cannot be
>   found that matches parameter name
>   'Docume ntRoutingResources'. At line:1
>   char:40
>   + Get-SPFeature -DocumentRoutingResources <<<<  -Site http://sp2010 |ft -auto
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-SPFeature],
>   ParameterB    indingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.Powe
>   rShell.SPCmdletGetFeature

I am not sure why I get that since when I just do

```
Get-SPFeature –Site http://sp2010
```

It shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you entered is passing a parameter called DocumentRoutingResources to the PowerShell command, which doesn't have such a parameter.
If you want just that item returned, you can filter for it quite easily:

```
Get-SPFeature -site http://tskm | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq "DocumentRoutingResources" }
```

The "?" is a shortcut for the cmdlet "where-object".

For your specific example, the cmdlet supports the 'identity' parameter as shown here:

```
 Get-SPFeature -identity DocumentRoutingResources -Site http://sp2010
```

Comment: I am just following this page. It seems to work other ones I tried just not that one. http://sharepoint2010tutor.blogspot.com/2011/02/activating-and-deactivating-features.html

Comment: You have it close but not quite.
This is what you're trying to do:
Get-SPFeature -identity DocumentRoutingResources -Site http://sp2010

Comment: @ Kevin Buchan - Ah I thought that was part of the name they where looking for.